# Same picture size in different size of android devices

Tags: android

I need to put a picture in activity in unique size(mm).this activity must show this picture in same size for diffrent devices with their own resolution,but when I try this,pic get diffrent size in diffrent devices...how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean image or ImageView ?

Comment: Well then simply put android:layout_width and height = "XXdp" where XX is the size of your ImageView in density indpendant pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create different Screen Sizes(`Layout files`) in `Res` PATH:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

e.x:

[image]